# how to redirect all requests to specific folder on webserver with IIS

Tags: iis

i need to handle 221 old webpages because they are indexed by google.
There are many different pages to same old folder eg.
olddomain/cars-for-sale/cars/vw-touran/aae51597-9a63-4188-b712-73953cecbbaa
olddomain/cars-for-sale/cars/bmw-530/bbc51597-9a63-4188-b712-74953cecbbaa

is it possible to handle all requests to olddomain/cars-for-sale/cars/ with one redirect in webconfig and if yes how?

i hope to be able to redirect all calls to olddomain/cars-for-sale/cars/ to one new url on the new webserver.

Thank you in advance

Michael Fiil (Denmark)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module Create a rule to redirect such requests.

Comment: Thank you Lex Li

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement looks like you want to redirect all subdomains to the main domain. If so, you can refer to this rule:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.olddomain.com$" />
         </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.olddomain.com/{R:0}" />
 </rule>
```

If this does not solve your problem, please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: Thank you samwu - my issue are solved. Placed the rule in folder on webserver and now all requests are redirected. Thank you